# Problema bucle while con suma Python

Tags: python

a partir de los siguientes datos:

```
restaurantes = [('Burger King', 'MA', 'Chicopee', '1284 Memorial Dr', '1020', '42.1927', '-72.5763'), ("Taco Bell", 'MA', 'Chicopee', '1606 Memorial Dr', '1020', '42.201117596', '-72.574102772'), ('Pizza Hut', 'MA', 'Easthampton', '113 Northampton St', '1027', '42.278666', '-72.671148'), ("Jack in the Box", 'MA', 'Holyoke', '285 Maple St', '1040', '42.20578', '-72.61053')]
```

He conseguido hacer la siguiente función que devuelve el porcentaje de "x" marca de restaurante en la variable restaurantes:

```
def porcentaje_burger_king(restaurante, name):
    nombres = [nombre for nombre, _, _, _, _, _, _ in restaurantes if nombre == name]
    result = (len(nombres)/len(restaurantes))*100
    return result
```

La cual se ejecuta con:

```
print(porcentaje(restaurantes, "Burger King")) #(0.25)
```

El problema es que no consigo crear una función que devuelva el porcentaje de cada marca que hay en la variable restaurantes. He probado con la siguiente función, la cual da datos erróneos:

```
def porcentajes_por_nombres(restaurantes):
    nombres = [nombre for nombre, _, _, _, _, _, _ in restaurantes]
    porcentajes = []
    indice = 0
    while indice < len(nombres):
        porcentaje_x = (len(nombres[indice])/len(restaurantes))*100
        porcentajes.append(porcentaje_x)
        indice +=1
    return porcentajes

print(porcentajes_por_nombres(restaurantes)) #Devuelve [275.0, 225.0, 225.0, 375.0] en vez de [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
```

Necesito el resultado en forma de lista, para luego poder utilizar la función zip con las variables nombres y porcentajes, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desempaquetas la tupla para extraer el nombre, pero el resto de elementos no te interesan y por eso usas `_`. Considera no desempaquetarla y usar un índice para recoger el primer elemento, así:

```
nombres = [r[0] for r in restaurantes if r[0] == name]
```

Naturalmente eso te dará nombres repetidos, lo que está bien para la función que quiere contar cuántas veces aparece cada nombre, pues `len(nombres)` te da ese dato. Pero para la otra función en la que simplemente necesitas recopilar todos los nombres, no te conviene que aparezcan repetidos. Por ello podrías usar un cojunto:

```
nombres = set(r[0] for r in restaurantes)
```

Después podrías recorrer ese conjunto y hacer uso de la otra función, para calcular el porcentaje. Puedes ir guardando en una lista las tuplas (nombre, porcentaje), para retornar directamente esa lista y no tener que hacer luego `zip()`. Por ejemplo así:

```
def porcentaje_restaurante(restaurantes, name):
    nombres = [r[0] for r in restaurantes if r[0] == name]
    result = (len(nombres)/len(restaurantes))*100
    return result

def porcentajes_por_nombres(restaurantes):
    nombres = set(r[0] for r in restaurantes)
    resultado = []
    for nombre in nombres:
      resultado.append((nombre, porcentaje_restaurante(restaurantes, nombre)))
    return resultado

porcentajes_por_nombres(restaurantes)
```

### Alternativa

Una forma aún más simple y breve es hacer uso del módulo estándar `collections`, que tiene una clase `Counter()` que sirve precisamente para contar las veces que se repite un elemento dentro de un iterable.

Podemos usarlo para contar los nombres de los restaurantes:

```
import collections
contador = collections.Counter(r[0] for r in restaurantes)
```

El resultado de la cuenta es un diccionario en el que cada clave es un elemento diferente (nombre de restaurante) y el valor es un entero con el número de veces que ha aparecido repetido. A partir de eso es trivial crear tu lista de (nombre, porcentaje):

```
import collections
resultado = []
total = len(restaurantes)
contador = collections.Counter(r[0] for r in restaurantes)
for nombre, veces in contador.items():
  resultado.append((nombre, veces/total*100))
```

Resultado:

```
[('Burger King', 25.0),
 ('Taco Bell', 25.0),
 ('Pizza Hut', 25.0),
 ('Jack in the Box', 25.0)]
```